# In Glassfish 4.1 is it possible to setup a deploy user which has less than asadmin permissions?

Tags: permissions, glassfish

We are looking to centralise deployment of WAR files into Glassfish via the `asadmin deploy` route.

I am aware that Glassfish supports autodeploy [via folder](https://serverfault.com/q/400754/163391), but want to manage the context and other parameters outside of war file.

At the moment we use deploy like this

```
asadmin --port 8048 deploy --name app-test --force --contextroot "/app/test" /usr/local/gfdeploy/app-1.2.war
```

However we want to manage this in a centralised script (DevOps style) and I also realise we can use "admin" user to perform this, but would like to create a user with ability to deploy, but not create/change other resources (JDBC Pools etc).

Is there any finer granulatity of permissions out of the box in Glassfish other than `asadmin` group that would allow deploy? or is there any way to setup a new group with required permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from Payara forum is that this is not currently supported, but there is an [open enhancement request](https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/1600) related to this.